# Poor exponential curve fitting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am getting quite poor results of exponential curve fitting in Matlab. In excel, exponential trendline yields excellent results (imho). What I'm doing wrong in Matlab?

example dataset:

1,0
1,0
0,8
0,8
0,8
0,8
1,1
1,1
0,9
0,9
0,8
0,8
0,8
0,8
0,7
0,7
0,6
0,6
0,7
0,7
1,1
1,1
1,0
1,0
0,9
0,9
0,8
0,8
0,9
0,9
2,1
2,1
1,9
1,9
2,1
2,1
6,5
6,5
6,0
6,0
5,7
5,7
6,4
6,4
11,1
11,1
10,9
10,9
10,2
10,2
8,5
8,5
12,6
12,6
11,8
11,8
9,9
9,9
11,6
11,6
10,6
10,6
9,7
9,7
9,6
9,6
8,2
8,2
10,1
10,1
9,0
9,0
9,0
9,0
8,9
8,9
8,9
8,9
8,2
8,2
11,8
11,8
15,8
15,8
13,1
13,1
14,8
14,8
13,4
13,4
13,6
13,6
15,4
15,4
16,9
16,9
16,7
16,7
25,9
25,9
23,4
23,4
24,5
24,5
26,6
26,6
24,2
24,2
22,7
22,7
21,2
21,2
21,0
21,0
17,3
17,3
42,1
42,1
40,8
40,8
41,3
41,3
39,7
39,7
42,4
42,4
42,6
42,6
89,0
89,0
196,2
196,2
228,1
228,1
385,4
385,4
746,7
746,7
701,8
701,8
633,7
633,7
1051,2
1051,2
1083,1
1083,1
1034,6
1034,6
1096,0
1096,0
1010,5
1010,5
1001,5
1001,5
835,6
835,6
886,1
886,1
1038,2
1038,2
867,4
867,4
821,8
821,8
753,8
753,8
704,5
704,5
616,4
616,4
555,5
555,5
854,1
854,1

yields

```
y = 0,4734*e^0,0442x, hence a = 0,4734 and b = 0,0442
```

but in Matlab, with code:

```
curveFitValues = fit(xdata,ydata,'exp1');
a = curveFitValues.a;
b = curveFitValues.b;
```

yields

```
y = 8,6631*e^0,0280x, hence a = 8,661 and b = 0,0280
```

which is not satisfying result, as seen in image below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp7PV.png)

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S: I need to do exponential curve fitting into millions of datasets and trying to find fastest algorithm, any ideas which is fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fit your data by using the `polyfit` function. I don't have the Curve Fitting Toolbox, but simply using `polyfit` serves me well usually. I stored your data as the variable `x` in my code.

```
t = 1:numel(x);
p = polyfit(t, log(x), 1);
figure; hold on
plot(x)
plot(t, exp(p(2)) * exp(p(1)*t))
set(gca, 'yscale', 'log')
hold off
```

[image]

This code takes `ln(x)` and fits it to `t` using a least squares method. Then you just convert back when you produce the plot.

`p` has values `p(1) = 0.0442` and `exp(p(2)) = 0.4375`.

Comment: Excellent, that indeed worked! Weird that curvefit didnt work; perhaps its designed for different types of datasets.

Thanks for help! :)